# Como salvar lista de objetos em Android

Tags: java, android

Quero salvar essa lista (List) apos sair da aplicação, e ao executar novamente a aplicação quero recuperar a instância da lista que havia sido salvar anteriormente.

```
private List<BluetoothDevice> listaDispositivoFavorito = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
```

Comment: Ta é o que Bluetooth tem haver com a historia? Não entendi nada.

Comment: To fazendo uma aplicacao q precisa salvar a lista List<BluetoothDevice> listaDispositivoFavorito = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>(); e depois recuperar quando a aplicacao for executada novamente

Comment: Entendi, existe algumas maneiras de gravar dados em Android, como [essas](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Acredito que deve elaborar melhor sua pergunta, recomendo que leia ["Como fazer uma boa pergunta?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e edite sua pergunta para que fique mais fácil de entender o que você deseja.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há algumas manerias de gravar/persistir dados em Android para recupera-los posteriormente, como demostrado [aqui na documentação](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html):

As mais comumente utilizadas são:

**[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)**

Que é uma local onde você pode guardar valores
    primitivos, no formato chave-valor (key-value pairs).

Em seu caso você pode serializar o objeto em json (em String), e recupera-lo e deserializa-lo posteriormente.

Você pode  utilizar a biblioteca [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) para serializar e deserializar o objeto.

**Para salvar:**

```
SharedPreferences  mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(listaDispositivoFavorito );
prefsEditor.putString("DISPOSITIVOS", json);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

**Para recuperar:**

```
SharedPreferences  mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = mPrefs.getString("DISPOSITIVOS", "");
Type type = new TypeToken<List<BluetoothDevice>>(){}.getType();
List<BluetoothDevice> obj = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

**[SQLite Databases](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)**

Que é uma base de dados SQL para Android. [Como utilizar aqui](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html).

Referências:

1. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref
2. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145606/how-android-sharedpreferences-save-store-object
4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819294/save-custom-object-array-to-shared-preferences
5. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981233/android-arraylist-of-custom-objects-save-to-sharedpreferences-serializable

Comment: estou conseguindo salvar mas ao realizar o seguinte codigo para recuperar: SharedPreferences save =  getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE); Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = save.getString("DISPOSITIVOS", "");
Type type = new TypeToken<List<BluetoothDevice>>(){}.getType();
List<BluetoothDevice> obj = gson.fromJson(json, type);
for (BluetoothDevice device : obj) {
Toast.makeText(this, device.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

Comment: eu printei : Toast.makeText(this,json,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); e executa normalmente, ou seja, existe o objeto mas na hora de executar Type type = new TypeToken<List<BluetoothDevice>>(){}.getType(); List<BluetoothDevice> obj = gson.fromJson(json, type); da erro

Comment: deu erro : at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584) at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.getName(BluetoothDevice.java:579)

Comment: @Fernando Acho que não pode ser feito dessa forma, a classe `BluetoothDevice` é um `Memento`, ele só possuí o atributo `mAddress` e o construtor dele é de pacote. Teria que usar um `Parcelable` pra salvar ele.

Comment: @Wakim estranho e que o se executar Toast.makeText(this, device.getAdress(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); da certo so nao consegui pegar o pelo metodo device.getName() ... mas o objeto mesmo assim fica "corretamente deserializado"?

Comment: @PedroRangel, o `getName` da errado porque ele usa o `BluetoothService`, que só é inicializado no contrutor, chamando o método `getService`. Dê uma olhada no código-fonte: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.java#BluetoothDevice.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String%29.

Comment: @Wakim verdade... obrigado, mas se eu tentar utilizar esse objeto que foi deserializado para se comunicar com outros dispositivos pode ocorrer problemas por conta dissu?

Comment: @PedroRangel, revolveu? Só marque como resposta quando realmente for resolvido.

Comment: @PedroRangel, você pode serializar os endereços (`getAddress()`) e chamar o `BluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(java.lang.String)` passando o endereço serializado. E para recuperar o `BluetoothAdapter` use `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()`. Mais detalhes em: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getRemoteDevice(java.lang.String)

Comment: @Wakim, no caso serializar um List<String>, e depois refazer o objeto Bluetooth, certo?

Comment: Isso mesmo @Fernando. Se puder incluir em sua resposta isso seria legal

Comment: @Fernando resolveu sim.. acho q nao precisa serializar... eu to conseguindo ate agora oq queria... a minha duvida era so na questao de getName() que nao e serializado por usa o BluetoothService como o Wakim tinha falado anteriormente, entao somente "parte" do objeto BluetoothDevice é serializado