# Salvar entrada do usuario em edittext

Tags: android, edittext

Sou novo usando o Android Studio e gostaria de salvar a entrada do usuário em um *edittext*
E mesmo que o usuário aperte o botão voltar ou feche o aplicativo o texto digitado permaneça no *edittext*

Será que alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Se tiver algum código edite a pergunta e adicione ele, coloque a tag(quadrinho azul) da linguaguem. Familiari-se com o site na [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e veja umas [dicas de como fazer perguntas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sugiro dar uma olhada na API de `SharedPreferences`. Esses dois links: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html e http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html e além dessas perguntas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25167/salvar-string-sharedpreference e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33677/como-salvar-lista-de-objetos-em-android/33698#33698 podem te ajudar.

Comment: @Wakim, creio que você poderia criar uma resposta =)

Comment: @Mateus, eu prefiro não criar uma resposta porque já temos várias perguntas/respostas sobre isso, apesar da pergunta não se referir explicitamente, eu caracterizaria como uma duplicata...

Comment: @Wakim, você que sabe, mas creio que você poderia usar o conteúdo das respostas existentes e acrescentar como utilizar nos eventos `onCreate` e `onDestroy`, que creio que seja a duvida do AP.

Answer (score 1):

O android, por sua vez, disponibiliza diversas formas de persistência de dados. Dentre elas estão:

1. [Salvar dados na Web](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#netw);
2. [um banco de dados privado](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db);
3. [Salvamento externo](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) e [Interno](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal);
4. [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

   No seu caso, podemos usar o mais simples, que é o **SharedPreferences**. Este método salva seus dados(valores) em chaves nativas do sistema para que você possa acessar ela em qualquer momento que você desejar. O modo de uso dela também é bem simples.

```
    public class Calc extends Activity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
       super.onCreate(state);
       // Put code

       // Regravar dados, se caso for necessário.
       SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
       String eValue = settings.getString("EditText_value", "xxxx");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
       super.onStop();

      // Este método faz com que, quando a aplicação for pausada, seja inserido um valor na Preference. Eu acredito que seja isto que você quer.
      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putString("Edittext_value", myEditText.getText().toString()); // Isto é oque você quer.

      // Salvar valor!
      editor.commit();
    }
```

**Observação**: Para gravar o valor de sua EditText, primeiro pegue o valor dela e passe para a SharedPreferences como uma string.

Para mais informações, consulte a documentação do Android: [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Answer (score 0):

Você vai precisar controlar a informação deste EditText usando o ciclo de vida da sua Activity no Android.

O ideal seria persistir a informação deste EditText, nos métodos **onPause()**, **onStop()**, e **onDestroy()** dentro da sua activity. E depois retornar o valor do mesmo nos métodos **onCreate()**, **onStart()**, **onRestart()**, e **onResume()**.

Ler um pouco e explorar sobre o ciclo de vida de uma activity pode te ajudar muito.

tem um pdf muito bom [aqui](http://www.facom.ufu.br/~bacala/ANDROID/4%20-%20GerenciandoActivity.pdf)

Comment: Obrigado Jhonattas! vou ler e tentar aqui.

Comment: Qualquer nova dúvida estarei aqui a disposição, pois já fui um iniciante no Android.

Comment: Oi jhonnattas tentei aqui mas nao consigo brother de jeito nenhum sao varias tentativas e nada, precisava apenas digitar algo no edittex , fechar o aplicativo e ao abrir o aplicativo encontrar o text digitado no edittext.Sou novo no android e java e sem um exemplo de codigo ta dificil.  Se puder postar um exemplo de codigo ficarei grato